# Is different X-Forwarded-For values per site an indicator for something malicious?

Tags: ip, header

I am using a mobile ISP to access the internet. I noticed something really weird: most sites (e.g. [www.whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com), https://www.iplocation.net/http-browser-header) report my IP as let's say IP A: XX.XX.XX.57.

However, a site that I'm hosting on Azure, **occasionally**  reports a different IP, let's say IP B: XX.XX.XX.208.
Examining the headers, this particular site reports: X-Forwarded-For: XX.XX.XX.208:40976.

Both IPs are on the ISPs network. That port on the X header shouldn't be there, should it? (a proxy of some sort?).

Is this something I should be worried about?

Comment: Is any of these your real external IP or don't you have a public external IP, like in case of [CG-NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT).  The latter is pretty common for mobile ISP or cable based ISP, in which case it might be not that unusual to have different public visible IP with different connections.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, well it seems most sites consider ip A to be my real public address, while on Azure, ip B is considered to be my public address...